# URLSession: Any way to read a file as it is being downloaded?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, urlsession

The use-case is that I want the user to be able to preview a song hosted at a remote URL. Fine, you say, just use AVPlayer. Yes, but I want to be able to cache the file locally if it is completely downloaded in the course of being previewed. As far as I can tell, there's no way to access the local data that AVPlayer downloads for its streaming playback. Likewise, there's no way to get access to the data being downloaded by URLSession until it is completely downloaded. So, I'd like to find a result using one of these approaches:

1. Access the data in AVPlayer once it has completed downloading it and save to a file.
2. Download the data progressively to the cached URL and have AVPlayer play it as enough data becomes available.

Are either of these scenarios possible? Is there some other scenario which will achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: I think `AVAssetResourceLoader` is what you're looking for. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloader
you should be able to pass the data through to the `AVPlayer` while also caching.
There's also `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`  `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams` but I think it's only for HLS.

Comment: Hmm... I don't see any methods on that object or its delegate protocol which would give me access to the data as it is being downloaded. It mostly seems to be designed for handling auth challenges and post-download data transformations. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have a look at this repo: https://github.com/leshkoapps/AVAssetResourceLoader

Comment: That solution seems to be less about AVAssetResourceLoader and more about the YanDisk SDK, which is a dependency I'm not willing to pull into our project.

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/renjithn/AVAssetResourceLoader-Video-Example
These are via https://github.com/search?q=AVAssetResourceLoader - I tried one of these out in the past, can't remember which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to this came from the `AlamoFire` source code. If you use a `URLSessionDataTask` in the traditional, non-combine way and have a controller conforming to `URLSessionDataDelegate`, then you can implement the `urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:)` protocol method to receive the data as it arrives, rather than waiting to receive it at completion. This allows you to directly write the data to a file of your choosing that is completely under your app's control.

Comment: Any chance you can explain what you did in any more detail for someone who is just learning Swift? Thanks!